# Why did Control not detect that rogue judges entered Peach Trees?

Tags: plot-explanation, dredd

After three rogue judges entered Peach Trees, and dismissed the two, the two would obviously have communicated to Control that they were dismissed by the three judges.

This would cause Control to detect something was wrong since they didn't send out the three judges.  Isn't it? So why didn't Control send additional backup?

Answer (score 4):

### Communications with Control are down in Peach Trees

Judges Lex, Chan and Alvarez receive their instructions from Ma Ma through some other communications method.  Official Judge communications with Control are not operating in the vicinity of Peach Trees.

Yes, it does appear that the two Judges who are dismissed are a loose end for Ma Ma and the rogue Judges, however this communications problem might be enough to delay Control sending more help. Their intervention in the story does happen towards the end of the movie, the story of which appears to happen only over a few hours, so it's not beyond possibility that the lack of backup is just down to timing.

Comment: Also, of course, who knows the three judges are rogue? At the point where they enter Peachtrees, the other judges don't know that and even the audience can't be sure until they see how they act. They are *Judges* after all and other judges and people will tend to trust them until it is too late.

Comment: Agreed @matt_black. Given the communication problems, instructions from another judge arriving at the scene would be trusted.  It's possible that Control will eventually realize that they didn't allocate 3 new judges to Peach Trees, but given the challenges of policing Mega City One, this might take some considerable time.  Judges have a lot of autonomy in conducting themselves, so it may not even be that surprising.